# Sql Server query with python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x

I need to know how to query a table in sql server. Everywhere i look it says to use pyodbc but they didn't make one for 3.4 .

Comment: What kind of connection are you trying to make? SQLite / MySQL / MsSQL?

Comment: In Python 3.4 you can use the pyodbc module which is labeled for use with Python 3.3

Comment: @Celeo, it clearly says for "SQL Server"...it's a Microsoft product.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't an official pyodbc for Python 3.4. However, as bernie mentions in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754083/sql-server-query-with-python#comment40272279_25754083), you can try the 3.3 version. Additionally, the University of California, Irvine provides an unofficial build for [pyodbc](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc) for Python 3.4. There is also the [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) package, as an option.

In any case, once you decide on which to utilize, you can use it by doing something like this. Realize this a very simple query.

```
import pyodbc
# Create connection
con = pyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}",server=SERVERNAME,database=DATA_BASE_INFO,uid=username,pwd=password)
cur = con.cursor()
db_cmd = "SELECT * FROM table_name"
res = cur.execute(db_cmd)
# Do something with your result set, for example print out all the results:
for r in res:
    print r
```

In the line that beings `con =`, there are several values for you to fill in.

- `server` needs to be server host information (either IP or DNS name), and possibly a port (default is 1435) `"dns.to.host.com,1435"`
- `uid` is the username you are logging in with
- `pwd` is the password of the user you are logging in with

Comment: Thank you very much, Can you edit it for future people so that db_cmd is db_cmd1 only place i got hung up on.